# How to completely eliminate a view in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am developing iOS App.

I would like to transfer the view of MasterViewController to the one of DetailViewController in the following code.

It goes well. But, in the following process it doesn't go well.

step1. I open the view of MasterViewController and tap goToDetailIcon, then the view of DetailViewController opens

step2. I tap my Home Button

step3. After several hours, I tap my App icon in Home Screen, the the view of DetailViewController opens.

step4. I tap goBackIcon and the the view of MasterViewController opens, however the view of DetailViewController remains behind the one of MasterView Controller. It remains much until I restart my iPhone.

In step3, if immediately I tap my App icon in Home Screen, it goes well. But after several hours, it doesn't.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

■MasterViewController.m

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *goToDetailIcon;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIScreen *sc = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect rect = sc.applicationFrame;
    _goToDetailIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.size.width-80,rect.size.height-85,77,77)];
    _goToDetailIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goToDetailIcon.png"];
    _goToDetailIcon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [_goToDetailIcon addGestureRecognizer:
     [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotoDetail)]];
    [self.view addSubview:_goToDetailIcon];
}

- (void)gotoDetail{

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailList"];
    detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

■DetailViewController.m

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *goBackIcon;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIScreen *sc = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect rect = sc.applicationFrame;
    _goBackIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.size.width-80,rect.size.height-85,77,77)];
    _goBackIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goBackIcon.png"];
    _goBackIcon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [_goBackIcon addGestureRecognizer:
     [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goBack)]];
    [self.view addSubview:_goBackIcon];
}

- (void)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. "Remains behind"? " it goes well"? Please explain in more detail what happens and what you want to happen.

Comment: How quickly are you pressing the button after reopening the app? Does the same thing happen if you wait a while with the app open?

Comment: Yes, it happens even if i wait for a while after reopen my app.

Comment: It goes well except "when I press home button in the state of the view of detailviewcontroller ,then after several hours I reopen".

Comment: The reason of bug is in the part of "[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];"?